# Ms ACCESS and queries: dates in graph not in order

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use queries in Ms ACCESS to create graphs (shown in forms) to represent monthly spend data on a supplier. I want the x axis to be the months in chronological order, and this is where I'm having issues.
[image]

The picture above shows that the x axis starts with april 2016, although the earliest date is august 2015.

The query code that creates the graph is the following:

```
SELECT (Format([DateStamp],"mmm"" '""yy")) AS Expr1, Sum([Item  Master].SpendPerMaterial) AS Expr2
FROM [Item Master]
WHERE ((([Item Master].SupplierName)=[Forms]![Supplier History]![List0]))
GROUP BY (Format([DateStamp],"mmm"" '""yy")),   (Year([DateStamp])*12+Month([DateStamp])-1);
```

[Item Master] is the table were all data is retrieved from. DateStamp refers to the column with months, SpendPerMaterial is the spend of a certain material in that month (which is aggregated since we look at the supplier level, not the material level), and List0 is a list where users can select a supplier from a list of suppliers.

Comment: You already have a sorting expression in your GROUP BY clause: `(Year([DateStamp])*12+Month([DateStamp])-1)`. If you put this as **first** GROUP BY expression (just exchange the two), it should sort correctly. I think.

Comment: @Andre, I tried this and it gives me the same graph as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never rely on the ordering of results from a query unless you include an explicit `order by`.  In your case, the results are ordered by the columns alphabetically (because of the `group by`).

You can fix this by adding:

```
order by max([DateStamp])
```

to the query.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Is the reason Access isn't figuring this out because the "dates" being passed in are actually strings (`Format([DateStamp],"mmm"" '""yy")`)? If The `DateStamp` were passed in directly to the chart and the chart formatted the date on the x-axis as `mmm 'yy` then is the order by not necessary anymore?

Answer (score 2):

I would add the following to your query, after your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY [datestamp] ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other suggesions on an aggregate totals by month report and no luck.  the only way i could get the actual month labels was by putting labels directly beneath the chart, which means altering it every month!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ive found a way of ordering it in the correct order.  in the report containing the graph, make the recordsource your aggregate query.  Add two expression fields in the query one for the year using YEAR(DateField) and the second for the month using MONTH(DateField).

in the report sort by the two expressions month within year and it comes out in the correct Gregorian Calendar order.